# Wowza Server not accepting connections on Local system

Tags: wowza

I just installed trial version of wowza on my system,but when I try to connect to wowza server on local network at port 1935 it does not accept connections. If I make connection on a different port on same machine it is accepted.
When I type `localhost:1935` in address bar it gives me the version of wowza server. when I tested the ports using `netstat -an` it described the port no 1935 as listening. But might be the possible reason for this.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? 1935 is one of the default ports for streaming, so you need to use an URL containing the app/stream name, ie. `rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/vod/sample.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

A response of `Listening` on port 1935 means that your Wowza server is listening on this port and is able to receive client connections. This is the expected behavior for the service. If you can't connect to your Wowza server streams, then it is likely because the packets are not getting to your Wowza streaming port. Then you can go through the following:

- Check that you don't have any firewall settings configured on your Wowza server blocking port 1935
- From the client device, launch the following URL `http://<wowzaServerIP>:1935/` and you should also be able to see the Wowza server version similar to launching `http://localhost:1935/` from within the Wowza server
- Run a Wireshark capture and see if the packets are getting to the server

Comment: i am facing similar kind of issue, when i run URL _http://<wowzaServerIP>:1935/_  from device, it said this site can't be reached. and when i click on video button in wowza gocoder app , it shows error "**connection refused from destination, error code 60**"

Comment: @Decveen Since you cannot reach port 1935 from the device, you likely have a firewall setting that is preventing TCP traffic. What platform are you using for your Wowza software? Windows usually has a built-in firewall, and you need to specify to allow inbound/outbound TCP traffic for port 1935.

Comment: thanks for the help, Issue resolved now. problem is with the ip. IP address conflicted of mobile and server.